# Is there a way to detect when the screen/sound is cast to another device by using an accessibility service?

Tags: android, service, accessibility, chromecast

I've been trying to find out how to detect when cast is active by using an accessibility service and taking an action for the user in this case, but to no avail. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What version on Android and what devices?

Comment: Mostly for any version, I guess. My app target is android 6+.